# OpenGL Performance

Tags: performance, opengl

First let me explain the application a little bit. This is video security software that can display up to 48 cameras at once. Each video stream gets its own Windows HDC but they all use a shared OpenGL context. I get pretty good performance with OpenGL and it runs on Windows/Linux/Mac. Under the hood the contexts are created using wxWidgets 2.8 wxGLCanvas, but I don't think that has anything to do with the issue.

Now here's the issue. Say I take the same camera and display it in all 48 of my windows. This basically means I'm only decoding 30fps (which is done on a different thread anywa) but displaying up to 1440fps to take decoding out of the picture. I'm using PBOs to transfer the images over, depending on whether pixel shaders and multitexturing are supported I may use those to do YUV->RGB conversion on the GPU. Then I use a quad to position the texture and call SwapBuffers. All the OpenGL calls come from the UI thread. Also I've tried doing YUV->RGB conversion on the CPU and messed with using GL_RGBA and GL_BGRA textures, but all formats still yield roughly the same performance. Now the problem is I'm only getting around 1000fps out of the possible 1440fps (I know I shouldn't be measuring in fps, but its easier in this scenario). The above scenario is using 320x240 (YUV420) video which is roughly only 110MB/sec. If I use a 1280x720 camera then I get roughly the same framerate which is nearly 1.3GB/sec. This tells me that it certainly isn't the texture upload speed. If I do the YUV->RGB conversion and scaling on the CPU and paint using a Windows DC then I can easily get the full 1440fps.

The other thing to mention is that I've disabled vsync both on my video card and through OpenGL using wglSwapIntervalEXT. Also there are no OpenGL errors being reported. However, using very sleepy to profile the application it seems to be spending most of its time in SwapBuffers. I'm assuming the issue is somehow related to my use of multiple HDCs or with SwapBuffers somewhere, however, I'm not sure how else to do what I'm doing.

I'm no expert on OpenGL so if anyone has any suggestions or anything I would love to hear them. If there is anything that I'm doing that sounds wrong or any way I could achieve the same thing more efficiently I'd love to hear it.

Here's some links to glIntercept logs for a better understanding of all the OpenGL calls being made:

Simple RGB: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BzGMib6CGH4TdUdlcTBYMHNTRnM

Shaders YUV: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BzGMib6CGH4TSDJTZGxDanBwS2M

Profiling Information:
So after profiling it reported several redundant state changes which I'm not surprised by. I eliminated all of them and saw no noticeable performance difference which I kind of expected. I have 34 state changes per render loop and I am using several deprecated functions. I'll look into using vertex arrays which would solve these. However, I'm just doing one quad per render loop so I don't really expect much performance impact from this. Also keep in mind I don't want to rip everything out and go all VBOs because I still need to support some fairly old Intel chipset drivers that I believe are only OpenGL 1.4.

The thing that really interested me and it hadn't occurred to me before was that each context has its own front and back buffer. Since I'm only using one context the previous HDCs render call must finish writing to the back buffer before the swap can occur and then the next one can start writing to the back buffer again. Would it really be more efficient to use more than one context? Or should I look into rendering to textures (FBOs I think) instead and continue using one context?

EDIT: The original description mentioned using multiple OpenGL contexts, but I was wrong I'm only using one OpenGL context and multiple HDCs.
EDIT2: Added some information after profiling with gDEBugger.

Comment: Unless your code is very, very, *very* wrong, any software profiler will show most of the time being spent in the swap function or other state-changing calls. The reason for this is that the driver caches as much as it possibly can, then dumps it all when an uncacheable call is made (swap and certain state changes). You need to use a graphics profiler that can communicate with drivers or the hardware directly, otherwise you'll keep seeing this sort of thing.

Comment: I don't know much about graphics profiling, but I've heard of gDEBugger. Are there any other suggestions? Any other tips on what to look for? I'll try out gDEBugger and post some more info afterwards, thanks.

Comment: A problem that I see is that the contexts will now swap synchronously. Unless you use one of the swap grouping extensions. http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/SGIX/swap_group.txt http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/NV/glx_swap_group.txt http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/NV/wgl_swap_group.txt – you could also use the swap_interval extension to set all but one of the contexts to unsynchronized swapping and using events on the swap in the main, synchronizing swap context to trigger the swap in all the other contexts.

Comment: datenwolf, I really like that idea, but I'm a little worried it may not work for the application. The documentation says a buffer swap has to be initiated for each drawable to initiate the swap. In a simple scenario where all video is 30fps and conditions are perfect. However, what if one video stream was 15fps or what if we stop receiving frames on one stream, etc. Also I'm a little interested in how that works since the backbuffer seems to be associated with the context and not the drawable and I only have one context.

Comment: I don't think swap group will be widely supported enough and I've read some things that seem to indicate its mainly meant for synchronizing swaps between two GPUs. I tried it on my ATI card which reported the extension, but when you query the max swap groups it reports 0 and any attempt to join a group always fails. That's kind of misleading. They shouldn't even bother advertising the extension if you can't do anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

What I try to make your application faster. I made one OpenGL render thread (or more if you have 2 or more video cards). Video card cannot process several context in one time, your multiple OpenGL contexts are waiting one of context. This thread will make only OpenGL work, like YUV->RGB conversion (Used FBO to render to texture). Camere`s thread send images to this thread and UI thread can picked up it to show on window.
You have query to process in OpenGL context and you can combine several frames to one texture to convert it by one pass. It maybe useful, because you have up to 48 cameras. As another variant if OpenGL thread is busy now, you can convert some frame on CPU.

From the log I see you often call the same methods:

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE)
glLoadIdentity()
glColor4f(1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000)
```

You may call it once per context and did not call for each render.

If I understung correct you use 3 texture for each plane of YUV

```
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,0,0,352,240,GL_LUMINANCE,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,00000000)
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,0,0,176,120,GL_LUMINANCE,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,000000)
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,0,0,176,120,GL_LUMINANCE,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,00000000)
```

Try to use one texture and use calculation in shader to take correct YUV value for pixel. It is possible, I made it in my application.